# How do we know that the $\ell^2$ inner product converges?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, convergence-divergence, hilbert-spaces

For vectors $a, b \in \ell^2$, the argument that I have seen for the convergence of the inner product is that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality says that
$$
|(a, b)| = \left| \sum_{i = 1}^n \overline{a_i} b_i \right| \le \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^n |a_i|^2 } \sqrt{ \sum_{i = 1}^n |b_i|^2 } = |a| |b|
$$
and the right side exists in the limit as $n \to \infty$, so the left side must exist in that limit as well.

But I am not convinced by that argument, because actually we have only shown that the left side is always less than or equal to the right side, not that it is equal. For example, $\sin(x) \le 1 + e^{-x}$ for all $x$, and the limit of $1 + e^{-x}$ as $x \to \infty$ exists, but the limit of $\sin(x)$ does not exist.

So how do we know that $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \overline{a_i} b_i$ exists?

Comment: The statement above (with proper $|\cdot|$ signs around the expressions in the first equality) shows that the sum of $\bar{a}_ib_i$ converges (because it's monotone and bounded), and then: absolute convergence of a sum implies conditional convergence.

Comment: The numbers are complex, how can the value be monotone. @march

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks, I think I've fixed it.

Comment: I would squeeze an extra inequality in there: take the absolute values inside the sum, writing $\sum_i |a_i||b_i|$, and *then* use the CS inequality from there. Then you really do have a monotone sequence, since they're all real numbers. @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Right, you need the absolute values are convergent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $a,b\in \ell^2(\Bbb{N};\Bbb{C})$. For each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n|\overline{a_i}b_i|&=\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i||b_i|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^2}\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2}\leq \|a\|_2\|b\|_2<\infty.
\end{align}
So, $\{\sum_{i=1}^n|\overline{a_i}b_i|\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is a weakly-increasing, bounded sequence of non-negative numbers, so its limit as $n\to\infty$ exists (infact equals the supremum over all $n$). i.e $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\overline{a_n}b_n|$ exists and is finite. Finally, absolute convergence of a series of complex numbers implies convergence of that series of complex numbers (this fact is actually equivalent to $\Bbb{C}$ being complete; and this holds more generally for any real/complex normed space as well: a normed vector space is complete if and only if every absolutely convergent series converges in the norm topology as well). Hence, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\overline{a_n}b_n$ exists (i.e $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n\overline{a_i}b_i$ exists in $\Bbb{C}$).